# File Handling errors in the following code

Tags: python-3.x, file, input, output

Is anyone able to trouble shoot and provide an explanation for the following apparent file handling errors in this code:

**Full Code listing on Trinket**

https://trinket.io/python/075581aa4f

**Using the following test data:**

```
Type in a number (1-7):  2
Add Name and Number
Name:  misscomputing
Number:  07373747273
Type in a number (1-7):  6
Filename to save:  numbers.txt
```

**The following error results:**

```
IOError: File not open for writing on line 74 in main.py
```

Furthermore, option 5 which is loading the file does not work either.

```
Type in a number (1-7):  2
Add Name and Number
Name:  misscomputing
Number:  03030483
Type in a number (1-7):  5
Filename to load:  numbers.txt
```

**Error**

ValueError: need more than 1 values to unpack on line 71 in main.py

**The two relevant functions are:**

```
def load_numbers(numbers, filename):
    in_file = open(filename, "rt")
    while True:
        in_line = in_file.readline()
        if not in_line:
            break
        in_line = in_line[:-1]
        name, number = in_line.split(",")
        numbers[name] = number
    in_file.close()

def save_numbers(numbers, filename):
    out_file = open(filename, "wt")
    for k, v in numbers.items():
        out_file.write(k + "," + v + "\n")
    out_file.close()
```

..but as mentioned the full code listing is here: https://trinket.io/python/075581aa4f

The examples are taken from the tutorial on https://en.wikibooks.org

Comment: Well, the "read file" function is failing because the supplied numbers.txt has the items separated by colons, not commas.  I'm extremely unimpressed with this "Trinket" site you're using: it's reporting errors in the caller of the failed function, rather than the actual site of the error, which is utterly useless.

Comment: Thanks jasonharper - I did actually try changing the numbers.txt file to commas instead of colon, but still the error: IOError: File not open for writing on line 74 in main.py

Comment: Everything except the "save" numbers does seem to work - to some degree anyway

Comment: It appears that Trinket doesn't support mode `"wt"` for file writing - try it with just `"w"`.

Comment: changing it to just "w" throws up another error: ValueError: need more than 1 values to unpack on line 71 in main.py  ....I think Trinket is awesome mostly, but the error handling could be improved as you say. I've emailed them and they're usually very good at getting back with suggestions or thoughts